# jQuery for each nav hover show and hide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show and hide on mouseenter and mouseleave so that the navigation can show the iframe which is actually the navigation.  I know that's weird and unusual, but anyway my code is below which works only on the first hover and I'm trying to have it loop over the navigation to show all nav hovers.

I do believe the .each() method would work I'm just not sure about how to apply it to my code.

Thanks for the help.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {  


            $("#primary-navigation li").bind("mouseenter",function() {
            $("#primary-navigation li iframe").show();
            });

            $("#primary-navigation li").bind("mouseleave",function() {
            $("#primary-navigation li iframe").hide();
            });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this will help.  I think you're using `bind` incorrectly. Should probably be `on`, `delegate` or just `hover`

```
$("#primary-navigation li").hover(
   function(){  $(this).find('iframe').show(); }, // mouseenter
   function(){  $(this).find('iframe').hide(); }  // mouseout
);
```